# Search by a value in Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here my data in firebase:

```
User:
|--0:
|--|--name: Alex
|--|--Age: 40
|--|--Weapons:
|--|--|--:axe: Axe
|--|--|--:sword: Sword
|--1:
|--|--name: John
|--|--Age: 22
|--|--Weapons:
|--|--|--:gun: Gun
|--2:
|--|--name: Mary
|--|--Age: 28
|--|--Weapons:
|--|--|--:shield: Shield
|--|--|--:sword: Sword
|
```

How can I search for users who use "Sword"?
I need a result in my nodeJS API like this:

```
[{"name":"Alex","Age":40,"Weapons":{"axe":"Axe","sword":"Sword"}},    
{"name":"Mary","Age":28,"Weapons":{"shield":"Shield","sword":"Sword"}}]
```

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple query against the child properties:

```js
ref.child("User").orderByChild("Weapons/sword").equalTo("Sword")
```

or

```
ref.child("User").orderByChild("Weapons/Sword").equalTo(True)
```

Just ensure that you are also indexing the values within Security Rules:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$userIndex": {
        "Weapons": {
          ".indexOn": ["Sword", "Shield", "Gun"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I solved with your **Weapon/sword**.
Actually, my rules also work with:
`"rules": {
    "Users": {
        ".indexOn": ["name", "age", "Weapons/axe",
                     "Weapons/shield", "Weapons/sword", "Weapons/gun"]
    },
}`

Comment: sounds good, I am not familiar with your project, the example I posted scales better for multiple fields - but so long as it works :)